# $http post does it call the function where url points to?

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I am doing an codeigniter aplication and have angular on my client side.So i want to post some information to my codeigniter controler.First question is do i need to jsondecode in my ci controler whe takeing information.And second question is can i call this function to where i am posting date some how?

This is my angular function

```
$scope.posaljiKontroleru = function () {
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost/psi/Pravljenjejela/dodajBazi',
                    data: $scope.prosek
                }).then(function (res) {
                    alert(res)
                }, function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            }
```

And this is my CI controler

```
public function dodajBazi(){

        $info = $this->input->post();
    }
```

Comment: you don't need to `decode` If you call on the controller `$this->input->post("var_name")`, but I still don't understand what do you mean at your second question.